# Adding a new row in pandas dataframe, adding one to the integer to create a new value

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to make a program that can generate "custom" barcodes for a digitization project.

Here is my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 

B = {'Static': ['99LIB'],
     'Number': [100000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(B)

print(df)
```

Then what I want to do is create a new row that still has static = '99LIB' but Number = 100001 (sequentially increasing).

Then I want print the last row and concat Static and Number together to print **only one** result that looks like 99LIB100001.

Each time it runs, I want it to increase by 1.

I am hoping to do it this way because many people will be working on this project and I want to prevent duplicate barcodes from being entered into our system.

I am a total beginner so I really appreciate any help you would be willing to give. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code creates a function you can call:

```
def new_barcode(df):
    new_num = df.tail(1).Number.values[0] + 1
    print(df.tail(1).Static.values + str(new_num))
    return df.append({'Static': '99LIB',
               'Number': new_num}, ignore_index=True)
```

Looking at your request, I imagine this would be the best way to solve your problem. Let me know if you have questions or if it doesn't match your expected output.

Edit:

Once you've built your project, whenever any user wants a new barcode, they run the function I've written in this format.

```
df = new_barcode(df)
```

Here the `df` is set to be equal to the output from the `new_barcode` function. The `new_barcode` function prints the new barcode and also adds the new barcode to the dataframe to avoid having a repeat.

Therefore in the future when you want a 100 barcodes, you can just run a simple for-loop like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    df = new_barcode(df)
```

This will save time and make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: Hi Siddarth!

Thank you so much! This looks like what I need. When I try to run, it doesn't seem to add a row or print. Just to clarify, this is how I'm runnning it:

    `import pandas as pd 
    B = {'Static': ['99LIB'],
    'Number': [100000]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(B)
        def new_barcode(df):
        new_num = df.tail(1).Number.values[0] + 1
        print(df.tail(1).Static.values + str(new_num))
        return df.append({'Static': '99LIB',
               'Number': new_num}, ignore_index=True)
df.tail(1)`

I have tired it with and without the line I just added.

Comment: Hi Maggie, The code I've written is written as a function. This means to just have to type `df = new_barcode(df)` to run the code as many times as you want. Here's a link to help to explain more (https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions). I've also modified the answer to give you an example.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your effort and help!

Comment: No problem, if you are happy with the solution, please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Hello again! After running the code for a single barcode, it successfully adds 1 barcode, but does not add additional rows - it simply stays at 100001 regardless of rerunning. 

I was also hoping to display the tail of the string, which I'm having trouble with as well.

Comment: `import pandas as pd 
B = {'Static': ['99LIB'],
     'Number': [100000]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(B)

def new_barcode(df):
    new_num = df.tail(1).Number.values[0] + 1
    return df.append({'Static': '99LIB','Number': new_num}, ignore_index=True)
    print(df.tail(1).Static.values + str(new_num))

df = new_barcode(df)
df.tail(1)`

Comment: Maggie, I'm quite sure you are rerunning the original code in which you create the dataframe again. I've attached a google notebook which will show that this code does append the additional rows (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13qyFE1RltvtCf8gqNP3DyRKWkkw6-56q?usp=sharing).  Notice that in this version I do not rerun the creation of the dataframe (`df = pd.DataFrame(B)`)

Comment: In addition, if you have another question, please create a different stackoverflow question, where people will be happy to answer it. Me answering questions in the comment section does not benefit the community as it is less reachable by people who have the same question in the future.